# What went wrong when trying to apply the Magento patch 5994?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, patches

I accessed the server through ssh ...

My files are in public_html so i uploaded patch in there

In ssh I ran commands to get in that folder

then:

```
chmod +x PATCH_SUPEE-5994_EE_1.14.1.0_v1-2015-05-14-05-05-02.sh
```

and finally:

```
./PATCH_SUPEE-5994_EE_1.14.1.0_v1-2015-05-14-05-05-02.sh
```

I received this output in terminal...

Can anyone help me understand this (being my first time doing this?)

```
Checking if patch can be applied/reverted successfully...
ERROR: Patch can't be applied/reverted successfully.

patching file app/code/core/Mage/Authorizenet/controllers/Directpost/PaymentController.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Admin.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Customer.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Dataflow/Model/Convert/Parser/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/ImportExport/Model/Export/Adapter/Csv.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/Controller/Router/Install.php
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Install/etc/config.xml
patching file app/code/core/Mage/Sales/controllers/Recurring/ProfileController.php
patching file downloader/Maged/Model/Connect.php
patching file downloader/Maged/View.php
patching file downloader/template/connect/packages_prepare.phtml
patching file downloader/template/messages.phtml
patching file get.php
can't find file to patch at input line 347
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
|index b4633bf..e6f8edc 100644
|--- lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
|+++ lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
42 out of 42 hunks ignored
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php
```

Comment: Did you check whether your install has the `lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php`? Maybe you removed it or excluded it from production? [This answer seemed to help another person having the same issue](http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/68089/20131).

Comment: where would i find this? in the same area as where app folder is? i certainly did not remove or edit it... maybe the theme install caused this??

Comment: Yeah, `lib` is a subdirectory of your Magento root.

Comment: could i just add it?

Comment: According to the answer I linked, you could get that file from a standard Magento install (for your version) if you don’t have it.

Comment: ok... downloading it now... what does it do may i ask? because everything works fin in the site, despite this not being in there

Comment: Seems like just a library for working with PEAR packages maybe? Not necessarily required for Magento to operate, probably some optional feature.

Comment: now getting same: >>>> patching file get.php
can't find file to patch at input line 347
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?
The text leading up to this was:
--------------------------
|diff --git lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
|index b4633bf..e6f8edc 100644
|--- lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
|+++ lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR.php
--------------------------
File to patch: 
Skip this patch? [y] 
Skipping patch.
42 out of 42 hunks ignored
patching file lib/PEAR/PEAR/PEAR5.php
patching file lib/Varien/Io/File.php

Comment: If the file now exists and is the one from the correct version of Magento that you are using, plus the patch is the right one for your version of Magento then I am out of ideas. Sorry!

Comment: no... you were correct!!!! +++++ i was stupid enough to ad the pear folder to root instead of putting it in lib/ :( patched successsfully!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

solution (thank you fantasticrice)

lib/PEAR/ was missing so downloaded magento 1.9.1, copied the pear folder and uploaded it to lib/

patched successfully

Answer (score 0):

I have exactly the same error (I reported yesterday but in an "old" question) in a fresh installation of 1.9.1.1 with downloader.php, there is no PEAR folder in the original download, do you need this PEAR folder or only to fix this issue ?

Own answer : Yes, that is a difference with downloader.php you don't get /lib/PEAR but with a manually download /lib/PEAR is included. So I copied /lib/PEAR and indeed now the patch is running normally without errors.

Thanks!